# Bug in Python's str.rstrip() function, or my own stupidity?

Tags: python, string, strip

Either this is a bug, or I'm about to learn something new about how Python behaves. :)

I have a dictionary filled with key/value pairs. Each key has a unique prefix, **`ias_XX_XX_`**. I'm attempting to get a list of every unique prefix in the dictionary.

1. First I get a list of all keys which end in `'_x1'`.
2. Next, I strip `'_x1'` from all of them using `rstrip('_x1'`).

This works fine for all of them, except for the last one, `ias_1_1_x1`. Instead of being stripped to `ias_1_1`, it becomes `ias_`. Run the code to see for yourself:

```
d = {
'ias_16_10_x2':     575, 
'ias_16_10_x1':     0, 
'ias_16_10_y1':     0, 
'ias_16_10_y2':     359,
'ias_16_9_x2':      575, 
'ias_16_9_x1':      0, 
'ias_16_9_y1':      18, 
'ias_16_9_y2':      341, 
'ias_1_1_y1':       0, 
'ias_1_1_y2':       359,  
'ias_1_1_x2':       467, 
'ias_1_1_x1':       108,
}

x1_key_matches = [key for key in d if '_x1' in key]
print x1_key_matches

unique_ids = []
for x1_field in x1_key_matches:
    unique_ids.append(x1_field.rstrip('_x1'))

print unique_ids
```

**Actual Output**: (Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2 (must change print to print() for 3.x to work))

```
['ias_16_10_x1', 'ias_16_9_x1', 'ias_1_1_x1']
['ias_16_10', 'ias_16_9', 'ias']   # <<<--- Why isn't this last one ias_1_1???
```

**Expected Output:**

```
['ias_16_10_x1', 'ias_16_9_x1', 'ias_1_1_x1']
['ias_16_10', 'ias_16_9', 'ias_1_1']
```

If I change the key's name from `ias_1_1` to something like `ias_1_2`, or `ias_1_3`, the glitch doesn't occur. Why is this happening?

Comment: In retrospect, it might have been more correct and less confusing if the argument of `rstrip` were a set instead of a list.  But sets were added later to Python.

Comment: You could always just slice off the final three characters: `uids = [key[:-3] for key in d if key.endswith("_x1")]`. Note that `endswith` is not the same as the test you have run.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The parameter to `rstrip()` is a set of characters to be stripped, not an exact string:

```
>>> "abcbcbaba".rstrip("ab")
"abcbc"
```

General hint: If you suspect a bug in some function, read its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Comment: never realized this! from the name it was easy to misunderstand as removing the 'thing' at the end..

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), emphasis added:

> The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. *The chars argument is not a suffix*; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.

Answer (score 4):

.rstrip's parameter isn't the string which we want to strip, it's the characters we want to strip. Check that examples:

```
>>> "12345678".rstrip("158")
'1234567'
>>> "12345678".rstrip("asd8qwe")
'1234567'
>>> "12345678".rstrip("78")
'123456'
>>> "1234568788".rstrip("78")
'123456'
```

Answer (score 3):

`.rstrip()` removes *all* combinations of matching characters, *not* the actual string you provide. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out instead:

```
unique_ids.append(re.sub('_x1$', '', x1_field)
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `unique_ids.append(x1_field.rsplit('_x1', 1)[0])`. Any benefits to using your regex solution instead?

Comment: Not really. Premature optimization maybe? :) But I don't know which one is the fastest.

Comment: But I must admit that I like your solution more... and based on some very quick testing, it seems to be at least twice as fast as the re one. Note to self: stop relying on regular expressions for everything.

Answer (score 0):

***rstrip* returns a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.**

For example:

```
>>> '   spacious   '.rstrip()
'   spacious'
>>> "AABAA".rstrip("A")
'AAB'
>>> "ABBA".rstrip("AB") # both AB and BA are stripped
''
>>> "ABCABBA".rstrip("AB")
'ABC'

########

>>> '   spacious   '.rstrip()
'   spacious'
>>> 'mississippi'.rstrip('ipz')
'mississ'
```

**If you are dealing with file names be extra careful,**

```
>>> "cosmac.csv".replace(".csv")
'cosma'
>>> "cosmac.csv".replace(".csv", "")
'cosmac'
```

Hope this helps!